# c# performance changes rapidly by looping just 0,001% more often

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection

I'm working on an UI project which has to work with huge datasets (every second 35 new values) which will then be displayed in a graph. The user shall be able to change the view from 10 Minutes up to Month view. To archive this I wrote myself a helper function which truncate  a lot of data to a 600 byte array which then should be displayed on a LiveView Chart.

I found out that at the beginning the software works very well and fast, but as longer the software runs (e.g. for a month) and the memory usage raises (to ca. 600 mb) the **function get's a lot of slower** (up to 8x).

So I  made some tests to to find the source of this. Quite surprised I found out that there is something like a magic number where the function **get's 2x slower** , just by changing **71494 loops to 71495** from **19ms to 39ms** runtime

I'm really confused. Even when you comment out the second for loop (where the arrays are geting truncated) it is a lot of slower. 
Maybe this has something to do with the Garbage Collector? Or does C# compress memory automatically?

Using Visual Studio 2017 with newest updates.

**The Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TempoaryTest
{
    class ProductNameStream
    {
        public struct FileValue
        {

            public DateTime Time;
            public ushort[] Value;
            public ushort[] Avg1;
            public ushort[] Avg2;
            public ushort[] DAvg;
            public ushort AlarmDelta;
            public ushort AlarmAverage;
            public ushort AlarmSum;
        }
    }


    public static class Program

    {
        private const int MAX_MEASURE_MODEL = 600;

        private const int TEST = 71494;
        //private const int TEST = 71495;//this one doubles the consuming time!
        public static void Main(string[] bleg)
        {
            List<ProductNameStream.FileValue> fileValues = new List<ProductNameStream.FileValue>();
            ProductNameStream.FileValue fil = new ProductNameStream.FileValue();

            DateTime testTime = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("TEST: {0} {1:X}", TEST, TEST);
            //Creating example List
            for (int n = 0; n < TEST; n++)
            {
                fil = new ProductNameStream.FileValue
                {
                    Time = testTime = testTime.AddSeconds(1),
                    Value = new ushort[8],
                    Avg1 = new ushort[8],
                    Avg2 = new ushort[8],
                    DAvg = new ushort[8]
                };
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    fil.Value[i] = (ushort)(n + i);
                    fil.Avg1[i] = (ushort)(TEST - n - i);
                    fil.Avg2[i] = (ushort)(n / (i + 1));
                    fil.DAvg[i] = (ushort)(n * (i + 1));
                }
                fil.AlarmDelta = (ushort)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                fil.AlarmAverage = (ushort)(fil.AlarmDelta / 2);
                fil.AlarmSum = (ushort)(n);
                fileValues.Add(fil);
            }


            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            /* May look like the same as MAX_MEASURE_MODEL but since we use int
             *  as counter we must be aware of the int round down.*/
            int cnt = (fileValues.Count / (fileValues.Count / MAX_MEASURE_MODEL)) + 1;

            ProductNameStream.FileValue[] newFileValues = new ProductNameStream.FileValue[cnt];
            ProductNameStream.FileValue[] fileValuesArray = fileValues.ToArray();


            //Truncate the big list to a 600 Array
            for (int n = 0; n < fileValues.Count; n++)
            {
                if ((n % (fileValues.Count / MAX_MEASURE_MODEL)) == 0)
                {
                    cnt = n / (fileValues.Count / MAX_MEASURE_MODEL);
                    newFileValues[cnt] = fileValuesArray[n];
                    newFileValues[cnt].Value = new ushort[8];
                    newFileValues[cnt].Avg1 = new ushort[8];
                    newFileValues[cnt].Avg2 = new ushort[8];
                    newFileValues[cnt].DAvg = new ushort[8];

                }

                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {
                        if (newFileValues[cnt].Value[i] < fileValuesArray[n].Value[i])
                            newFileValues[cnt].Value[i] = fileValuesArray[n].Value[i];
                        if (newFileValues[cnt].Avg1[i] < fileValuesArray[n].Avg1[i])
                            newFileValues[cnt].Avg1[i] = fileValuesArray[n].Avg1[i];
                        if (newFileValues[cnt].Avg2[i] < fileValuesArray[n].Avg2[i])
                            newFileValues[cnt].Avg2[i] = fileValuesArray[n].Avg2[i];
                        if (newFileValues[cnt].DAvg[i] < fileValuesArray[n].DAvg[i])
                            newFileValues[cnt].DAvg[i] = fileValuesArray[n].DAvg[i];
                    }
                    if (newFileValues[cnt].AlarmSum < fileValuesArray[n].AlarmSum)
                        newFileValues[cnt].AlarmSum = fileValuesArray[n].AlarmSum;
                    if (newFileValues[cnt].AlarmDelta < fileValuesArray[n].AlarmDelta)
                        newFileValues[cnt].AlarmDelta = fileValuesArray[n].AlarmDelta;
                    if (newFileValues[cnt].AlarmAverage < fileValuesArray[n].AlarmAverage)
                        newFileValues[cnt].AlarmAverage = fileValuesArray[n].AlarmAverage;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! The threshold for my system is between 71924 (takes ~20ms) and 71925 (takes ~30ms)

Comment: Looks like it's the garbage collection which is making the difference. Try adding `GC.Collect();` just before you start the stopwatch. When I do that, the difference goes away - so looks like it just so happens that you are timing the garbage collection as well as your own code.

Comment: To further support my contention that it's the garbage collector, try chaning the initialisation of `fileValues` to: `fileValues = new List<ProductNameStream.FileValue>(TEST);`. This will prevent it from reallocating the array inside the List (since it will be big enough to hold the entire final list) and hence there won't be so much garbage to collect. For me, this reduces the time even without the `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: when I do GC.Collect elapsed time reduces from 19-18 to 16. tested many times.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Try changing the value of `TEST` to something higher, such as 80000.

Comment: you nailed the number. now it goes from 30-31 to 18 with GC.Collect. @MatthewWatson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely being caused by the garbage collector, as you suggested.

I can offer two pieces of evidence to indicate that this is so:

1. If you put `GC.Collect()` just before you start the stopwatch, the difference in times goes away.
2. If you instead change the initialisation of the list to `new List<ProductNameStream.FileValue>(TEST);`, the difference in time also goes away.

(Initialising the list's capacity to the final size in its constructor prevents multiple reallocations of its internal array while items are being added to it, which will reduce pressure on the garbage collector.)

Therefore, I assert based on this evidence that it is indeed the garbage collector that is impacting your timings.

Incidentally, the threshold value was slightly different for me, and for at least one other person too (which isn't surprising if the timing differences are being caused by the garbage collector).

Comment: linked list also works good here (though it will be a little slower but it wont create garbage like list), of course if OP doesn't need random access to its records he can use Linked list

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is inefficient and is forcing you to do a lot of allocations during computation. Have a look of this[fixed size array inside a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)
. Also preallocate the list. Don't rely on the list to constantly adjust its size which also creates garbage.

Comment: I was told to never use unsafe code when I started programming in C#. But I'll give it a try. I like your second idea much more, hadn't thought about it yet. I'll make it a fixed 600 struct array and allocate the byte arrays at the beginning and then just change the values

Comment: As long as all needed memory is preallocated, you don't have to use fixed buffer. It is just an convenient way of preallocating memory. Fixed buffer has an additional benefit of improving cache performance. But by how much will depend on profiling. Preallocating the list makes sure you have a clean start. It alone helps but is not the ultimate fix. The problem may surface again when the data size increases.